# Watchpoint conditions in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse

sorry, I was looking for information about this topic but I did not find anything useful so I post here the probably trivial question.

I use eclipse galileo cdt in mac os x. I create watchpoints, and for some of them I am able to specify that the debug run stops when the variable takes some value, for instance aaa==10. But I want now what the debug run stops when aaa less than -50. So I tried aaa<-50 but nothing. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Someone seems to have had [exactly the same probl](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.tools.cdt/msg19044.html)... oh wait, it is you;)

Could this be a side-effect of [bug 213076](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=213076)?
In short, modifying an *existing* breakpoint could lead to some *extra* quotes around the new condition, making it not running properly.

Do you have the same symptom with a *new* breakpoint?